# How do i tell the compiler there is no more input

Tags: java, cygwin

My friend is showing me how basic java works however he didn't show me how the code works fully and I wanted to know How do i tell any compiler  there is no more input? because it simply lets me keep typing forever I'm sure the code is right its just when I compile the code it just leaves space and I can keep pressing enter to enter more characters however I don't know how to stop it

```
import java.io.*;

class FileStats {

    /**
     * Implements the entire process (reading and reporting).
     *
     * @param args is not used.
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        // Variables to hold the various character class counts.
        int lowerCase = 0;
        int upperCase = 0;
        int whiteSpace = 0;
        int otherChars = 0;
        int totalChars = 0;

        // Read the (standard) input
        while (true) {
            // Quit if there's no more input.
            int input = System.in.read();
            if (input < 0) break;

            // Cast the input to a character.
            char c = (char) input;

            // Tally up the statistics.

            totalChars++;

            if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {
                lowerCase++;
            } else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {
                upperCase++;
            } else if (' ' == c || '\t' == c || '\n' == c) {
                whiteSpace++;
            } else {
                otherChars++;
            }
        }

        // Report the statistics
        System.out.println(totalChars + " Total Characters");
        System.out.println(lowerCase + " Lower-Case Characters");
        System.out.println(upperCase + " Upper-Case Characters");
        System.out.println(whiteSpace + " White-Space Characters");
        System.out.println(otherChars + " Other Characters");
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two separate steps: 1) Edit the code with an editor 2) Compile the code with a compiler. It's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: sorry i know the question is very confusing  however its just that when i do compile the code in a compiler such as cygwin nothing hapens for example I will type" Javac FileStats.java" compile it then use java FileStats to call the class then i enter multiple numbers then and now im trying to make the code finish and print out the statistics however i dont know how to do that

Comment: well considering you have a `while(true)` statement in there it won't ever stop... you need to get rid of that and possible think of a better condition to loop maybe like... `while(readInNumber != -1)  keep going...`

Comment: Press ctrl-d to send EOF.

Comment: Just for your reference this question has nothing to do with the compiler. The compiler is for taking your code and turning it into a program. What you want to ask is how to make your program finish running.

Comment: Harold ... so >>edit<< the question to say that!  When you ask *"How do i tell any compiler there is no more input?"* ... it is like asking *"How do I ask the pilot for a cup of tea?"* Answer:  (to both questions) is "You don't!".  The Java compiler doesn't read your input.  (The JRE does).

Comment: Man why are being such a dick dude im just trying to learn if you didn't have anything usefully to say then down vote my question and mark it as spam and thank you to everyone that has helped me so far like i said its basically my first time dealing with anything relatively like this so @StephenC give a guy a break man

Comment: @harold I just updated my answer to show you the small logical error you made in your if statement. Your code is fine otherwise.

Comment: @HaroldSullivan - I am trying to point out that it is >>your responsibility<< to express yourself accurately and clearly.  Do you want people to understand you?  Or would you prefer us to simply downvote your questions and move on to someone whose questions make sense?  If you express yourself like that in an exam or a job interview, you will be marked down.  E.g. people will think *"this guy doesn't know the difference between compiling and running a program"*.  If you don't learn to express yourself accurately, it will be "career limiting".

Answer (score 3):

You hava a `while (true)`, so, yes the program will always loop asking for numbers from the keyboard.

I guess you need another `else if` in the loop catching a 'special' character meaning that the loop has to end, and from there, you can just call `break`.

E.g.

```
...
else if (c == '0') {
    break;
}
...
```

Comment: @HaroldSullivan I just updated my answer to show you the small logical error you made in your if statement. Your code is fine otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The InputStream *read()* method returns a byte as an int in the range 0 to 255.

```
int input = System.in.read();
```

Take a look at your conditional statement again:

```
if (input < 0) break;
```

The value of input will always be *greater than 0* and *less than 255*.
Your condition only evaluates to true if ***input is less than 0***, which will not happen unless the end of the stream is reached.

You could edit this line and use:

```
if (input == 80) break;
```

Then if you typed "P", it will break out of the loop and display the results as you need.

Alternatively, you could use a *Scanner* from *java.util.Scanner*

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You can use the *read()* function to read the next String of input. The java String class has a method called *charAt(int index)* which returns the char at a specific index in the string. You can use this method to get the first character of input:

```
char c = reader.next().charAt(0);
```

If you put this together:

```
while (true) {
    char c = reader.next().charAt(0);
if (c == '.') break;
```

This way you don't have to worry about casting *ints* to *chars*. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For newcomers in java is better to start from Scanner.

Try [java.util.Scanner](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjd05rT2MbMAhVFqB4KHQ3SC3sQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F1.5.0%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Futil%2FScanner.html&usg=AFQjCNF9K24MUQ2IzDJVLUDCu_Pj5ypXuQ&sig2=wlBdsr2ORLoXHR1K7J7v4w&bvm=bv.121421273,d.dmo):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class FileStats {

    /**
     * Implements the entire process (reading and reporting).
     *
     * @param args is not used.
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        // Variables to hold the various character class counts.
        int lowerCase = 0;
        int upperCase = 0;
        int whiteSpace = 0;
        int otherChars = 0;
        int totalChars = 0;

        // Read the (standard) input
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String line = scanner.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {

            // Tally up the statistics.
            totalChars++;

            char c = line.charAt(i);
            if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {
                lowerCase++;
            } else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {
                upperCase++;
            } else if (' ' == c || '\t' == c || '\n' == c) {
                whiteSpace++;
            } else {
                otherChars++;
            }
        }

        // Report the statistics
        System.out.println(totalChars + " Total Characters");
        System.out.println(lowerCase + " Lower-Case Characters");
        System.out.println(upperCase + " Upper-Case Characters");
        System.out.println(whiteSpace + " White-Space Characters");
        System.out.println(otherChars + " Other Characters");
    }
}
```

Try the code [there](http://ideone.com/NnVDDu).